# Storage for Properties.Settings for Application Scope in a .Net Library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a .Net library that I am using to access a third party REST service.  I stored the security information in the Properties/Settings.  It works great.  The thing is, I wanted to make sure my security information wasn't sitting around in a text file somewhere that could be compromised.  I looked in the application.exe.config file and I didn't see a section for application settings.  There is not a .config file for the .dll.  I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019 and it said that application settings would not work in a library/dll.  This is clearly not the case since it is working.  Does anyone know where it stores the settings for a library/dll?  Is there a best practice to store sensitive data for a windows forms app using .Net Framework 4.7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other projects, dlls can also use Properties.Settings to store user data.

[image]

As to store sensitive data, You can try to encrypt / decrypt the data. Then store the encrypted string into Settings.

The following is an encrypt demo you can refer to.

```
// dll
namespace dlltest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.EncryptedString);
            string key = "A123456."; // 8 or 16 characters
            DES des = new DES();
            Console.WriteLine("1.Encrypt\n2.Decrypt");
            string option = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (option)
            {
                // Encrypt
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Input a string");
                    string str = Console.ReadLine();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.EncryptedString = des.DesEncrypt(str, key);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    break;

                // Decrypt
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine(des.DesDecrypt(Properties.Settings.Default.EncryptedString, key));
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DES
    {
        // DES Encrypt
        public string DesEncrypt(string pToEncrypt, string sKey)
        {
            StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(pToEncrypt);
                des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
                des.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                foreach (byte b in ms.ToArray())
                {
                    ret.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                }
                ret.ToString();
            }
            catch { }
            return ret.ToString();
        }

        // DES Decrypt
        public string DesDecrypt(string pToDecrypt, string sKey)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[pToDecrypt.Length / 2];
                for (int x = 0; x < pToDecrypt.Length / 2; x++)
                {
                    int i = (Convert.ToInt32(pToDecrypt.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16));
                    inputByteArray[x] = (byte)i;
                }
                des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
                des.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
            }
            catch { }
            return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you by chance know where the properties are actually stored at rest for the application scope and for the user scope?